# "us" units on relaxation times $T_j$ in the IBM backends

Tags: ibm-q-experience

A pretty lame question but, the backends relaxation times $T_1,T_2$ are given in **us** units. What are those? (Frequencies are given in GHz... Is it really $\mu s$ but IBM can't display the $\mu$ in the information chart?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they mean microseconds.

It's very common to write $\mu s$ as $us$, e.g. because it can be typed more easily. Sometimes it's forced by some software constraint (e.g. fixed width fonts often become not-fixed-width if you stray outside ASCII).